# Authentication in WebAPI using Owin token and Onion architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac, jwt, onion-architecture

I'm trying to create a new WebApplication using onion Architecture. IOC is based on Autofac and defined in a Bootstrapper project using WabActivator. 
My authentication part is based on Jwt token using Owin.

```
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/generateToken"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider =   new CustomOAuthProvider(), <--my probelm
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://localhost:18292/")
        };

        // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

    }
```

I'm trying to inject a service resolved by IOC in the CustomProvider(). I have been searching and i found a solution

```
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
  {

    //............
  IService<User> _service = (IService<User>)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IService<User>));

    //...........

    }
```

In my first attempt using this configuration to call the user service i have an exception :

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates
>   that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by
>   a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web
>   integration always request dependencies from the
>   DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime,
>   never from the container itself.

so i changed InstancePerRequest() to InstancePerLifetimeScope(), now it's working.

Questions:

1/ knowing that the i dont have a direct access(from WebAPI) to Autofac Container (defined in bootstrapper project), is

> IService _service =
>   (IService)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IService));

a good option if no, is there any others options ?

2/ knowing that Owin startup is a singleton and the authentication process is by request (i'm not sure), whta's the impact of changing autofac resolution from  InstancePerRequest to  InstancePerLifetimeScope?

thanx :)